# QwtPlotCurve doesn't show up on graph

Tags: c++, qt, qwt

I'm currently working on a project in which I load a huge number of data points on a graph (something like 50,000, so I can zoom in as much as I want).

I wanted to test how the commands worked, so I thought I'd try out the code with 10 pieces of data, but unfortunately my curve refuses to show up on my graph.

```
QwtPlot *leftGraph;
leftGraph = new QwtPlot;
leftGraph->setCanvasBackground(Qt::white);

leftGraph->setMaximumHeight(200);

leftGraph->setAxisScale(0, 0.0, 20.0, 2.0);
leftGraph->setAxisScale(2, 0.0, 20.0, 2.0);
```

and

```
QwtPlotCurve *curve = new QwtPlotCurve();
curve->setStyle(QwtPlotCurve::Lines);
curve->setCurveAttribute(QwtPlotCurve::Fitted, true);


const double x[] = {0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 10, 13, 14, 19};
const double y[] = {17, 16.5, 8, 3, 5, 7.5, 9, 10, 12, 14};

curve->setSamples(x, y, 10);
curve->attach(leftGraph);
```

Any ideas? Many thanks.

Comment: To adjust the Y axis scale, shouldn't it be `leftGraph->setAxisScale(2, 0.0, 20.0, 2.0)` instead of `leftGraph->setAxisScale(1, 0.0, 20.0, 2.0)`? Did you try calling `leftGraph->replot()`? Does it work if you don't manually set the scale (let it autoscale)?

Comment: >.> .... <.< ..... >.< ...replot.... so simple. I was indeed missing that. Thanks!! ^_^. Dunno which index indicates which axis, but 0 and 2 works for me!

Comment: I've added an answer, should you care to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling `leftGraph->replot()` to make the curve appear.